# Swift annotation change view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating annotations and I would like by clicking on an annotation to switch to a different view.

And pass to the different view a string.

Here is my annotations :

[image]

Code :

```
var annot = MKPointAnnotation()
annot.title = tab[i]["title"].string
annot.subtitle = tab[i]["description"].string
annot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tab[i]["latitude"].doubleValue, longitude: tab[i]["longitude"].doubleValue)
self.mapView.addAnnotation(annot)
```

And by clicking to the title or adding an info button at the left I want to switch to a different view.

If you have any links/example thank you so much

Comment: In iOS 9 this will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You would generally not have tapping an annotation view take you directly to another scene. Instead, you would generally specify an accessory for the annotation's callout in `viewForAnnotation` that would perform a segue to the destination scene. Your `prepareForSegue` would then pass the necessary information to that destination controller.

   See [Creating Callouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW28) in the *Location and Maps Programming Guide.*
2. You technically could transition to the next scene when the annotation is tapped by (a) implement `viewForAnnotation` that specifies that no callout should be shown, and (b) implement `didSelectAnnotationView` which performs the segue.

Regardless of which approach you adopt, you must obviously specify the `delegate` for the map view.